# How to turn off subtotals in Pivot Table programmatically - poi java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table

I'm programmatically creating a pivot table in Excel.

Basically I want to set 'Subtotals' to None in Field Settings for a cell.

Right Click on a cell -> select 'Field Settings' -> in the popup window set 'Subtotals' to 'None' as shown in the attached image.

Any help is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is this xls or xlsx Excel format? You probably need to save the file once without this setting and a second time with this setting while not changing anything else. Then depending on the file-format that you are using there are tools that can show what is the difference and if and how you might be able to do this in Apache POI.

Comment: @centic What are these tools of which you speak?  In my case the format is xlsx.  I have been doing the save both ways and compare xml, but that gets old fast.

Comment: For XLSX there is org.apache.poi.dev.OOXMLPrettyPrint which is provided as part of the POI. It allows to "normalize" the XML files in an .xlsx as much as possible. You run it on both files and get out two new files which should b so two filese easier to compare. However you still need to do the compare then and some differences cannot be weeded out by the tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache POI XSSFPivotTable setDefaultSubtotal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305976/apache-poi-xssfpivottable-setdefaultsubtotal)

Comment: See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305976/apache-poi-xssfpivottable-setdefaultsubtotal/40480654#40480654