# How to set default value in Apache POI pivot table report filter

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a worksheet with data in it, I am trying to create a pivot table with report filter. I want to set default value to the report filter.

```
pivotTable.addReportFilter(13);
```

column contains 0's and 1's, I would like to set 0 as my default value in the report filter.

Answer (score 3):

At first this question is not answerable in that general context as it is asked now. Creating pivot tables using apache poi is in beta state until now. So we need not only the high level apache poi API but also the underlying low level objects. And we need exactly to know which kind of data shall be in the pivot table. To be general able creating pivot tables from all kind of data, as Excel can do, there is much more effort  necessary. Microsoft has programmed this in decades with big teams of programmers. From this apache poi is far away.

Until now apache poi adds as much pivot field items of type "default" (`<item t="default"/>`) as rows are present in the data range, if the pivot fields where used as axis fields. 
 This is because they don't want to have a look at the data, and so they are assuming as much different values as rows where in the data.

This is fine because Excel will rebuild its pivot cache while opening. But if we want preselect items, then this is not fine. Then we must know what items there are that can be preselected.

So we need at least as much items, as we want preselecting, as numbered items: `<item x="0"/><item x="1"/><item x="2"/>`...

And we need to build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;

import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;

class PivotTableTest4 {

 private static void setCellData(Sheet sheet) {
  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
  Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue("Name");
  cell = row.createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue("Value1");
  cell = row.createCell(2);
  cell.setCellValue("Value2");
  cell = row.createCell(3);
  cell.setCellValue("City");

  for (int r = 1; r < 15; r++) {
   row = sheet.createRow(r);
   cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("Name " + ((r-1) % 4 + 1));
   cell = row.createCell(1);
   cell.setCellValue(r * new java.util.Random().nextDouble());
   cell = row.createCell(2);
   cell.setCellValue(r * new java.util.Random().nextDouble());
   cell = row.createCell(3);
   cell.setCellValue("City " + ((r-1) % 3 + 1));  
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
   XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

   //Create some data to build the pivot table on
   setCellData(sheet);

   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(
    new AreaReference(new CellReference("A1"), new CellReference("D15")), new CellReference("H5"));
   //Configure the pivot table
   //Use first column as row label
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
   //Sum up the second column
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 1);
   //Avarage the third column
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.AVERAGE, 2);
   //Add fourth column as page filter
   pivotTable.addReportFilter(3);
/*   
   Apache poi adds 15 pivot field items of type "default" (<item t="default"/>) here. 
   This is because there are 15 rows (A1:D15) and, because they don't have a look at the data, 
   they are assuming max 15 different values. This is fine because Excel will rebuild its pivot cache while opening. 

   But if we want preselect items, then this is not fine. Then we must know what items there are that can be preselected.

   So we need at least as much items as we want preselecting as numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/><item x="2"/>... 

   And we must build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items.
*/
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    //take the first 3 items as numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/><item x="2"/>
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(3).getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(3).getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long)i);
    //build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items 
    //<sharedItems><s v="City 1"/><s v="City 2"/><s v="City 3"/></sharedItems>
    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(3).getSharedItems().addNewS().setV("City " + (i+1));
   }

   //Now we can predefinite a page filter. Second item, which is "City 2", in this case.
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPageFields().getPageFieldArray(0).setItem(1);

   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("PivotTableTest4.xlsx");
   wb.write(fileOut);
   fileOut.close();
   wb.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

This needs the full jar of all of the schemas, `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar`,  as mentioned in the [FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025).