# How to set Multiple default value in Apache POI pivot table report filter

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need some help, I'm working on a project where I need to create a pivot table with report filter. Now I want to set **Multiple** default value to the report filter. I've gone through this previously posted question Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354088/how-to-set-default-value-in-apache-poi-pivot-table-report-filter)! 
I couldn't find anything online related this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There has not much changed at creating pivot tables using apache poi since my last answer. So my code in the linked Q/A in your question only can extended a little bit for fulfilling the requirement selecting multiple items as default in page filter. A code which would be general able creating pivot tables from all kind of data, as Excel can do, is further on not possible.

If the need is selecting multiple items, first `MultipleItemSelectionAllowed` needs to be set in appropriate pivot field.

Then for each item which not shall be selected `H`(idden) needs set true.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.SpreadsheetVersion;

import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;

class PivotTableTest4 {

 private static void setCellData(Sheet sheet) {
  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
  Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue("Name");
  cell = row.createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue("Value1");
  cell = row.createCell(2);
  cell.setCellValue("Value2");
  cell = row.createCell(3);
  cell.setCellValue("City");

  for (int r = 1; r < 15; r++) {
   row = sheet.createRow(r);
   cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("Name " + ((r-1) % 5 + 1));
   cell = row.createCell(1);
   cell.setCellValue(r * new java.util.Random().nextDouble());
   cell = row.createCell(2);
   cell.setCellValue(r * new java.util.Random().nextDouble());
   cell = row.createCell(3);
   cell.setCellValue("City " + ((r-1) % 4 + 1));  
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
   XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

   //Create some data to build the pivot table on
   setCellData(sheet);

   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(
    new AreaReference(new CellReference("A1"), new CellReference("D15"), SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007), new CellReference("H5"));
   //Configure the pivot table
   //Use first column as row label
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
   //Sum up the second column
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 1);
   //Avarage the third column
   pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.AVERAGE, 2);
   //Add fourth column as page filter
   pivotTable.addReportFilter(3);
/*   
   Apache poi adds 15 pivot field items of type "default" (<item t="default"/>) here. 
   This is because there are 15 rows (A1:D15) and, because they don't have a look at the data, 
   they are assuming max 15 different values. This is fine because Excel will rebuild its pivot cache while opening. 

   But if we want preselect items, then this is not fine. Then we must know what items there are that can be preselected.

   So we need at least as much items as we want preselecting as numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/><item x="2"/>... 

   And we must build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items.
*/
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    //take the first 4 items as numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/><item x="2"/><item x="3"/>
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(3).getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(3).getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long)i);
    //build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items 
    //<sharedItems><s v="City 1"/><s v="City 2"/><s v="City 3"/><s v="City 4"/></sharedItems>
    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(3).getSharedItems().addNewS().setV("City " + (i+1));
   }

   //Now we can predefinite a page filter. Second item, which is "City 2", in this case.
   //pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPageFields().getPageFieldArray(0).setItem(1);

   //If the need is selecting multiple items, first MultipleItemSelectionAllowed needs to be set.
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(3).setMultipleItemSelectionAllowed(true);
   //Then set H(idden) true for all items which not shall be selected. First ("City 1") and fourth ("City 4") in this case.
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(3).getItems().getItemArray(0).setH(true);
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(3).getItems().getItemArray(3).setH(true);

   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("PivotTableTest4.xlsx");
   wb.write(fileOut);
   fileOut.close();
   wb.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

This needs the full jar of all of the schemas, `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar`,  as mentioned in the [FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025).