# How to get items of a pivot field Apache POI - Multiple items selection/removal?

Tags: java, apache-poi, pivot-table

After creating an Excel pivot table via Apache POI, I would like to access a specific pivot field definition to get its explicit items list. Instead of "Select all" activated by default, I would like to select/remove some items from this list programmatically.

Is there any solution to do it properly in Java with Apache POI library ?
I am also open to alternative solutions like using Aspose features eventually.

Because I did not find any solution to get the explicit items, here is my workaround solution to select explicit items from the known list, helped by the following topic : [How to set Multiple default value in Apache POI pivot table report filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51288301/how-to-set-multiple-default-value-in-apache-poi-pivot-table-report-filter)

This simply consists into adding a dummy element and delete it afterwards

```
public void setPivotFieldDataFilterPositive(String sheetName, String pivotName, String fieldName, List filterValuesList) { 

    XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = getPivotTable(sheetName, pivotName);

    int fieldIndex = table.findColumnIndex(fieldName);
    List<CTPivotField> pivotFieldsList = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldList();
    CTPivotField ctPivotField = pivotFieldsList.get(fieldIndex);
    for (int i = 0; i < filterValuesList.size(); i++) {
        //take the first 4 items as numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/><item x="2"/><item x="3"/>
        ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
        ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long)i);
        //build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items 
        //<sharedItems><s v="City 1"/><s v="City 2"/><s v="City 3"/><s v="City 4"/></sharedItems>
        pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(fieldIndex).getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(filterValuesList.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println("count : "+pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(fieldIndex).getSharedItems().sizeOfSArray());
    ctPivotField.setMultipleItemSelectionAllowed(true);

    //additional dummy element to hide it afterwards
    ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(filterValuesList.size()).unsetT();
    ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(filterValuesList.size()).setX((long)filterValuesList.size());
    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(fieldIndex).getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(null);//item with empty name

    //hide dummy element
    ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(filterValuesList.size()).setH(true);//item hidden but an empty item still visible on the list
    //ctPivotField.getItems().removeItem(filterValuesList.size()); //does not keep the filtering
}
```

It works but it's a crazy way to do it and I would like to avoid modifying the underlying XML structure too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [Aspose.Cells for Java](https://products.aspose.com/cells/java/) for the task. You can use relevant APIs to get items of a pivot field, you can do multiple items selection and removal accordingly.
See the following example for your reference.

e.g.

**Sample code:**

```java
        Workbook wb_demo = new Workbook("f:\\files\\Book1.xlsx");
        PivotTable pt_demo = wb_demo.getWorksheets().get(0).getPivotTables().get(0);

        //Get the first Pivot column field
        PivotField src_t_field = pt_demo.getColumnFields().get(0);
        src_t_field.setMultipleItemSelectionAllowed(true);

        System.out.println(src_t_field.getName());
        System.out.println("Total Items: " + src_t_field.getItems().length);
        System.out.println("Total Items: " + src_t_field.getPivotItems().getCount());

        PivotItemCollection collection_src_t = src_t_field.getPivotItems();
        System.out.println(collection_src_t.getCount());
        for (int i = 0; i < collection_src_t.getCount(); i++)
        {
            PivotItem item = collection_src_t.get(i);
            System.out.println(item.getName());

            if(item.getName().equals("0.5 kg"))
            {
               item.setHidden(true);
            }
            else if(item.getName().equals("1 kg"))
            {
                    item.setHidden(false);
            }
            else if(item.getName().equals("1.5 kg"))
            {
                    item.setHidden(true);
            }
             else if(item.getName().equals("2.5 kg"))
            {
                    item.setHidden(false);
            }
            else if (item.getName().equals("3 kg"))
            {
                    item.setHidden(true);
            }
            else if(item.getName().equals("6.5 kg"))
            {
                    item.setHidden(false);
            }

        }

        pt_demo.calculateData();

        wb_demo.save("f:\\files\\out1.xlsx");
```

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Your Aspose's solution is tested and worked as expected, thank you. I accept it since there is no Apache POI solution proposed for now.