# How to disable intermediate total using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to disable intermediate total  using Apache poi, I'm using apache poi for this, i want intermediate total should be disabled

Here is input in excel for understanding

[image]
[image]

Expected result 
[image]

```
  public class ApacheCreatePivotTable
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet();

            //Create some data to build the pivot table on
            setCellData(sheet);

          //  System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum());

            XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(new AreaReference(new CellReference(0,0),new CellReference(4,sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum()-1)), new CellReference(0,7));

            pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
            pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);


            pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3);

            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(2).setAxis(
                    org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STAxis.AXIS_COL);


            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(2).addNewItems();
            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(2).getItems().addNewItem().setT(
                    org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STItemType.DEFAULT);

            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewColFields().addNewField().setX(2);

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("output.xlsx");
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            wb.close();
        }

        public static void setCellData(XSSFSheet sheet)
        {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Row row1 = sheet.createRow(0);
            // Create a cell and put a value in it.
            Cell cell11 = row1.createCell(0);
            cell11.setCellValue("Names");
            Cell cell12 = row1.createCell(1);
            cell12.setCellValue("falility");
            Cell cell13 = row1.createCell(2);
            cell13.setCellValue("date");
            Cell cell14 = row1.createCell(3);
            cell14.setCellValue("cost");

            Row row2 = sheet.createRow(1);
            Cell cell21 = row2.createCell(0);
            cell21.setCellValue("tom");
            Cell cell22 = row2.createCell(1);
            cell22.setCellValue("Nal stop");
            Cell cell23 = row2.createCell(2);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(2017,07,18);
            cell23.setCellValue(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
            Cell cell24 = row2.createCell(3);
            cell24.setCellValue(10);

            Row row3 = sheet.createRow(2);
            Cell cell31 = row3.createCell(0);
            cell31.setCellValue("Ram");
            Cell cell32 = row3.createCell(1);
            cell32.setCellValue("Vadgao");
            Cell cell33 = row3.createCell(2);
            cal.set(2017,07,19);
            cell33.setCellValue(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
            Cell cell34 = row3.createCell(3);
            cell34.setCellValue(12);

            Row row4 = sheet.createRow(3);
            Cell cell41 = row4.createCell(0);
            cell41.setCellValue("Terk");
            Cell cell42 = row4.createCell(1);
            cell42.setCellValue("Deccan");
            Cell cell43 = row4.createCell(2);
            cal.set(2017,07,20);
            cell43.setCellValue(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
            Cell cell44 = row4.createCell(3);
            cell44.setCellValue(11);

            Row row5 = sheet.createRow(4);
            Cell cell51 = row5.createCell(0);
            cell51.setCellValue("tom");
            Cell cell52 = row5.createCell(1);
            cell52.setCellValue("baner");
            Cell cell53 = row5.createCell(2);
            cal.set(2017,07,18);
            cell53.setCellValue(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
            Cell cell54 = row5.createCell(3);
            cell54.setCellValue(20);

        }
    }
```

Please help me with it.

Comment: in which excel version can you produce your expected result? i used your code and also create a pivot table by hand with the same data and both look the same (like your current result)

Comment: this doesn't answer my question

Comment: ohh  sorry,i'm using libray office of mint,i'll try google sheet

Comment: I have tried with google sheet but i'm getting the same result

Comment: `libre office` you mean i suppose. this is far away from microsoft excel and therefore does look otherwise. your current result is as it should be in every .xlsx file and therefore this question is invalid because there is no problem at all

Comment: My concern is that, is their any way that will create the pivot as my expected ,not using any sheet directly from java

Comment: simply said, **NO**. longer answer: your current result should be your expected result with apache poi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see, your main requirement is getting rid of the subtotals. This is possible using [org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTPivotField](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTPivotField.java#CTPivotField)`.setDefaultSubtotal(false)`.

This was asked also here [Apache POI XSSFPivotTable setDefaultSubtotal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305976/apache-poi-xssfpivottable-setdefaultsubtotal/40480654#40480654).

With your example:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

  public class ApacheCreatePivotTable
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet();

            //Create some data to build the pivot table on
            setCellData(sheet);

            //System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum());

            XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(new AreaReference(new CellReference(0,0),new CellReference(4,sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum()-1)), new CellReference(0,7));

            pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);

    //set tabular layout instead of tree layout
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(0).setOutline(false);

    /*   
    Apache poi adds 5 pivot field items of type "default" (<item t="default"/>) here. 
    This is because there are 5 rows (A1:C5) and, because they don't have a look at the data, 
    they are assuming max 5 different values. This is fine because Excel will rebuild its pivot cache while opening. 

    But if we want changing defaults, then this is not fine. Then we must know what items there are.

    So we need at least as much items, as where different ones in the data, as numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/> 

    And we must build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items.
    */


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     //take the first 3 items as numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/>
     pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(0).getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
     pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(0).getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long)i);
    }

    for (int i = 4; i > 2; i--) {
     //remove further items
     pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(0).getItems().removeItem(i);
    }

    //set new items count
    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(0).getItems().setCount(3);

    //build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items 
    //<sharedItems><s v="tom"/><s v="Ram"/><s v="Terk"/></sharedItems>
    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldList().get(0).getSharedItems().addNewS().setV("tom");
    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldList().get(0).getSharedItems().addNewS().setV("Ram");
    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldList().get(0).getSharedItems().addNewS().setV("Terk");

    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(0).setDefaultSubtotal(false);

            pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);




            pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 3);

            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(2).setAxis(
                    org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STAxis.AXIS_COL);


            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(2).addNewItems();
            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(2).getItems().addNewItem().setT(
                    org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.STItemType.DEFAULT);

            pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().addNewColFields().addNewField().setX(2);

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("output.xlsx");
            wb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            wb.close();
        }

        public static void setCellData(XSSFSheet sheet)
        {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Row row1 = sheet.createRow(0);
            // Create a cell and put a value in it.
            Cell cell11 = row1.createCell(0);
            cell11.setCellValue("Names");
            Cell cell12 = row1.createCell(1);
            cell12.setCellValue("falility");
            Cell cell13 = row1.createCell(2);
            cell13.setCellValue("date");
            Cell cell14 = row1.createCell(3);
            cell14.setCellValue("cost");

            Row row2 = sheet.createRow(1);
            Cell cell21 = row2.createCell(0);
            cell21.setCellValue("tom");
            Cell cell22 = row2.createCell(1);
            cell22.setCellValue("Nal stop");
            Cell cell23 = row2.createCell(2);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(2017,07,18);
            cell23.setCellValue(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
            Cell cell24 = row2.createCell(3);
            cell24.setCellValue(10);

            Row row3 = sheet.createRow(2);
            Cell cell31 = row3.createCell(0);
            cell31.setCellValue("Ram");
            Cell cell32 = row3.createCell(1);
            cell32.setCellValue("Vadgao");
            Cell cell33 = row3.createCell(2);
            cal.set(2017,07,19);
            cell33.setCellValue(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
            Cell cell34 = row3.createCell(3);
            cell34.setCellValue(12);

            Row row4 = sheet.createRow(3);
            Cell cell41 = row4.createCell(0);
            cell41.setCellValue("Terk");
            Cell cell42 = row4.createCell(1);
            cell42.setCellValue("Deccan");
            Cell cell43 = row4.createCell(2);
            cal.set(2017,07,20);
            cell43.setCellValue(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
            Cell cell44 = row4.createCell(3);
            cell44.setCellValue(11);

            Row row5 = sheet.createRow(4);
            Cell cell51 = row5.createCell(0);
            cell51.setCellValue("tom");
            Cell cell52 = row5.createCell(1);
            cell52.setCellValue("baner");
            Cell cell53 = row5.createCell(2);
            cal.set(2017,07,18);
            cell53.setCellValue(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
            Cell cell54 = row5.createCell(3);
            cell54.setCellValue(20);

        }
    }
```

Changings to your code are commented.

Result in Excel:

[image]