# Apache poi not allowing blank values for pivot creation

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

I am trying to create a pivot table using apache poi for normal values it is working fine but if there is null or blank values xlsx file gets repaired and pivot gets removed on opening it.

Here is my code:

```
static void addRowLabel(XSSFPivotTable pivotTable, XSSFSheet dataSheet, AreaReference areaReference, int column) { 

      DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(java.util.Locale.US);
      //apache poi creates as much fields for each as rows are in the pivot table data range
      pivotTable.addRowLabel(column);

      java.util.TreeSet<String> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>();
      for (int r = areaReference.getFirstCell().getRow()+1; r < areaReference.getLastCell().getRow()+1; r++) {
          if (dataSheet.getRow(r).getCell(column) != null && dataSheet.getRow(r).getCell(column).getCellType() != CellType.BLANK) {
              uniqueItems.add(formatter.formatCellValue(dataSheet.getRow(r).getCell(column)));
          } else {

              uniqueItems.add("");
          }
      }

      CTPivotField ctPivotField = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(column);
      int i = 0;
      for (String item : uniqueItems) {
       //take the items as numbered items
       ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
       ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long)i);
       //build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items 
       pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(column).getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(item);
       i++;
      }

      //set pivot field settings
      ctPivotField.setOutline(false); // no outline format
      ctPivotField.setDefaultSubtotal(false); // no subtotals for this field

      if (ctPivotField.getDefaultSubtotal()) i++; 
      for (int k = ctPivotField.getItems().getItemList().size()-1; k >= i; k--) {
       ctPivotField.getItems().removeItem(k);
      }
      ctPivotField.getItems().setCount(i);

     }
```

This method is used for adding rows and below code is to start execution:

```
 public static void secondway( ) throws IOException {
         try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("/opt/source.xlsx")); 
                   FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("/opt/ExcelResult.xlsx") ) {

               XSSFSheet dataSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
               XSSFSheet pivotSheet = workbook.createSheet("Pivot");
               
               int firstRow = dataSheet.getFirstRowNum();
               int lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRowNum();
               int firstCol = dataSheet.getRow(0).getFirstCellNum();
               int lastCol = dataSheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
               CellReference topLeft = new CellReference(firstRow, firstCol);
               CellReference botRight = new CellReference(lastRow, lastCol - 1);

               AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference(topLeft,botRight, SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);

               XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.createPivotTable(areaReference, new CellReference("A1"), dataSheet);

               addRowLabel(pivotTable, dataSheet, areaReference, 0);
               addRowLabel(pivotTable, dataSheet, areaReference, 2);
               
               pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 1, "test");

               workbook.write(fileout);
         
         
         }
     }
```

I  am not sure what is wrong am I doing or how to support blank values. Please help.

Input that I am using:

[image: ![enter image description here]

While opening shows below error and removes piivot:
[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: And please show a complete example as I have done in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60887605/java-how-to-create-a-pivot-with-apache-poi/60891686#60891686.

Comment: Thank you for the response and sorry I forgot to add headers in question, I have updated my question. but still it didn't worked.

Comment: I am using poi 4.1.2

Comment: what dose it shows for blank value in pivot?

Comment: Strange then why it's not working in my scenario, let me debug more in that case. thanks for the help

Comment: Do a `System.out.println(areaReference);` after creating the `AreaReference`. What does it print? If you have empty cells in the sheet after the column Header3, then the area reference points to columns without field names. That could lead to that issue.

Comment: HI, I have updated inputs for which it is not working

Comment: *Argh* Pivot table takes values case insensitive. So to determine unique items a `java.util.TreeSet<String> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);` is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aim of the `addRowLabel` method, which seems to be from my answer [java: How to create a pivot with apache poi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60887605/java-how-to-create-a-pivot-with-apache-poi/60891686#60891686), is to correct `apache poi`, which creates as much items for each pivot field as rows are in the pivot table data range. But it should be as much items as unique items are in pivot field data column.

To get the unique items per column a `java.util.TreeSet` is used as this cannot contain duplicate elements.

But `Excel` pivot table takes the values case insensitive. So `11 KD` and `11 kd` are the same value for `Excel` pivot tables. Thats why `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` needs to be used as `Comparator` while creating the `java.util.TreeSet`.

Do changing:

```
...
java.util.TreeSet<String> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>();
...
```

into

```
...
java.util.TreeSet<String> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
...
```

and it should work.